# gulp.watch Слежка за определённым файлом в директории

Tags: gulp

Добрый день
Есть вот такие таски gulp

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
    gulp.src('js/scripts.js')
            .pipe(uglify())
            .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
            .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'))
 });

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch('js/scripts.js', ['js']);
});
```

в процессе работы, обнаружил, что

```
gulp.watch('js/scripts.js, ['js']); === gulp.watch('js/, ['js']);
```

т.е. таск js отработав - складывает минифицированный файл в эту же директорию... не красиво, но не мной придумано и мне изменять нельзя... к сожалению
как только мин файл появляется в директории срабатывает watch... зацикливание..
Есть ли решение, чтобы следить за одним файлов во всей директории?

Comment: Кавычки ошибочно удалены пока правил пути проекта, для сокращения, в самом файле всё просто, иначе была бы ошибка, здесь прошу прощения за неточность написания..

Comment: ситуация такова - галп файл лежит локально на машине, а сам проект находится на сервере подключенном как сетевой диск, если я копирую файловую структуру на машину, всё работает как должно.. на сервере же получается зацикливание.., чего то я наверное не понимаю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы кавычки не закрываете здесь `.pipe(gulp.dest('js/))` и `gulp.watch('js/scripts.js, ['js']);` может быть это влияет.

Написал такой gulpfile.js, у меня отрабатывает, как и ожидается: минифицирует, добавляет суффикс, кладет в папку, не зацикливает.

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');

gulp.task('js', function () {
  gulp.src('js/scripts.js')
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('js'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('js/scripts.js', ['js']);
});
```